# entire function with $f(n)=n^2$ for integers $n$

Tags: holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function with $f(n)=n^2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Is it true that then $f(z)=z^2$ for all complex numbers $z$?

I think it's not but I dont't get an example. Can you tell me one?

Comment: How about $g(z)=\cos(2\pi z)z^2$?

Comment: $ z^2 + \sin 2 \pi z $

Comment: You can add any function such that $g(n)=0$.